# ignored properties are lost when fetched from RLMResult with objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have this model:

```
enum PhotoState: String {
  case New = "New"
  case Downloaded = "Downloaded"
  case Failed = "Failed"
}

class Photo: RLMObject {
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var imageURLString = ""

  var state = PhotoState.New

  override class func primaryKey() -> String! {
    return "id"
  }

  override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject]! {
    return ["state"]
  }
}
```

I am presenting this in a table view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    photos = Photo.allObjects()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if let count = photos?.count {
        return Int(count)
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let photo = photos?.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row)) as? Photo {
        downloadPhoto(photo, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

func downloadPhoto(photo: Photo, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Fake Download
    switch photo.imageURLString.lastPathComponent {
    case "7.png":
        photo.state = .Failed
    default:
        photo.state = .Downloaded
    }
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

If I tap a row the row should update and have a new state, but the photo record's state property is back to .New again.

Does RLMResult's objectForIndex initialize a new model instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever an object is stored in Realm, only properties that are not "ignored" are stored and retrievable again. Whenever you get objects from Realm the "ignored" properties will just come out with default values.

So using the "ignored" properties is mostly usefull when you e.g. have a standalone object which is used outside of Realm initially. And when you then want to add it to Realm, you want certain properties to not be stored.

The properties of a realm object are not stored in the object itself. They are retrieved /stored directly in the database and the object is just acting as a proxy.

Comment: So that means RLMResults.objectAtIndex fetches the model from the db?
So I have to do this:

`var photos = [Photo]()`
    
`for photo in Photo.allObjects() {
  photos.append(photo as Photo)
}`

Comment: Yes, objectAtIndex fetches the model. Ignored properties are best used to transform some save property from the model and should not be used to save state. You are better off saving the integer in a property```savedState``` and create a getter for ```state``` that uses that to create the correct enum.

Comment: Yes it does - depending on what you mean by "fetches". There is no copy of data from the database to the object. The object and the database appears to be one and the same thing - no copying of values into properties of the object; only proxying.

Comment: Indeed, each time a RLMResults fetch the same database entry, it will be a difference object instance. So the memory-cached UIImage will be lost.